# Laplace's method for unknown function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

I am currently dealing with a problem of bounding the expression
$$
\frac{B(0.5,\beta)\max_{0\leq x<1} h(\alpha x)(1-x^2)^\beta }{\int_{-1}^{1}h(\alpha t)(1-t^2)^{\beta-1} dt}
$$
for $\alpha,\beta >0$ and increasing $h()\geq 0$. I know that for some nice $h()$ this is bounded but not in general (e.g. indicator function can break it as $\beta \rightarrow \infty$). I tried to work out the asymptotic using Laplace's method:

For big $\beta$ (if I am not mistaken) this is trivial because $(1-x^2)$ has maximum at 0 and so
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}h(\alpha t)(1-t^2)^{\beta-1} dt = \int_{-1}^{1}h(\alpha t)\exp((\beta-1)\log(1-t^2)) dt\approx h(0)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta-1}}
$$
from which the above can be bounded easily by $h(\alpha x_0)/h(0)$ for $x_0$ being argmax of the numerator.

I would also like to investigate the case where $\alpha$ is big, under some form of $h()$ (e.g. exponential form $h(\alpha x) = c^{\alpha x}$), but since $h$ is increasing the maximum is not attained in the interior and the second function is 0 at $x=1$, is there any way to investigate this case under some restrictions of $h$? Or some other way how to bound the above expression uniformly under some form restrictions of $h()$ like positivity?

Comment: The Lapalce method is in fact more general than that. It is not a problem if the slowly varying function vanished at the endpoint. See http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.iii See also http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.E12 for more general kernels.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The expansion of the second function at x=1 is however not very friendly in this case, so I am not sure how could I apply the generalization of the Watson's lemma. I tried to substitute y= 1-x to simplify the problem, but I cannot see how I could proceed any further.

Comment: Now I see that after the substitution the form matches more the definition of Watson's lemma from wikipedia with $y^{\beta−1}$ in front of the second function.